# How to properly configure NGINX to serve Vite-React front-end container and CakePHP API back-end container

Tags: reactjs, nginx, cakephp, docker-compose

I'm currently trying to config my NGINX docker instance to serve both front and back-end services to create a brand new applications with:

- CakePHP as my Back-End RestAPI;
- ReactJs as my Front-End;
- MySQL as the Database and;
- NGINX as a web server and reverse proxy.

I'm struggling with the NGINX configuration, since I seek a setup where all four containers run at the same time... While NGINX serves the frontend application, the front-end would send requests to the API (CakePHP/PHP-FPM container) passing through the NGINX container and the Back-End container would do some queries to MySQL container.

The sorce code is in this repository: https://github.com/eddyyxxyy/cake-react-nginx

Today (Jul 19, 2023) I've tried to do this configs:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
name: cake-react-template
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db-mysql
    volumes:
      - ./backend/database:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=fictional_db
      - MYSQL_USER=eddyxide
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=leandoer

  fpm:
    build: ./backend/app
    container_name: app-php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./backend/app:/var/www/html/api
      - ./backend/app/config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    links:
      - mysql

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: server-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./backend/app:/var/www/html/api
      - ./frontend/:/var/www/html/app
      - ./backend/app/logs/nginx.log:/var/log/nginx
      - ./backend/server/nginx:/etc/nginx
    ports:
      - "8765:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - fpm
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html/app;
    index index.html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        index index.htm index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/api(.*) {
    root /var/www/html/api/webroot/;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    try_files $uri /api/webroot/index.php$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    }
}
```

But ended up with file not found when accessing /api:

[image: File not found error while accessing /api]

What can I do for this setup/template work the way I mentioned? What should I change in order for this to work as my new standard Cake-React start project?

And, is this setup proper for production servers? If not, why?